# Sign a file with SSL certificate for iOS "Shared Web Credentials" API

Tags: openssl, certificate, digital-signature, smime

I got a web server certificate from Symantec, which is enabled for the `Digital Signature` X509v3 key usage, and that I'd like to use to sign the `apple-app-site-association` JSON file required by the [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/) API.

When I sign a file using the following command:

```
$ openssl smime \
-sign \
-inkey my.key \
-signer certificate.pem \
-certfile SymantecSSG4.crt \
-noattr -nodetach \
-in content \
-outform DER -out result
```

…I get no error. But when I try to verify `result` it fails with an error:

```
$ openssl smime -verify -inform DER -in result
Verification failure
140735229006672:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:328:Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: I ***think*** *"Verify error:unsupported certificate purpose"* tells you the problem is with *Key Usage (KU)* or *Extended Key Usage (EKU)*. You can use `openssl x509 -in <cert> -inform {PEM|DER} -text -noout` to see what you are allowed to do with it. Its likely *Server Authentication*, *Key Encryption* and possibly *Client Authentication*.

Comment: @jww I can understand why the question seems off topic. I skipped giving the context since it doesn't really add to the description of the technical problem, but my question is related to setting up the Shared Web Credentials API on iOS so I believe it has its place here. The fact that tags such as openssl etc existed comforted that idea.

Comment: Unfortunately my certificate _does_ support the `Digital Signature` extended key usage, as mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section **4.4.4 Extended Key Usage Extension** of RFC 5750 is clear that a certificate's `Extended Key Usage` extension must include the `emailProtection` OID in order for the public key in the certificate to be used to verify signed S/MIME messages.

> If the extended key usage extension is present in the certificate,
>      then interpersonal message S/MIME receiving agents MUST check that it
>      contains either the emailProtection or the anyExtendedKeyUsage OID as
>      defined in [KEYM].

This is why OpenSSL complains when trying to verify the signed S/MIME payload. For it to become really valid, I would need to request a new certificate with the `emailProtection` extended key usage.

In practice, though, I could verify that iOS 8.3 happily accepts such a signed file when used for [Shared Web Credentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/), which was my intended usage.